# How to make a C++ class be "return"able? (or dynamics of return of user-defined types)

Tags: c++, class, coding-style

What happens when we use a return statement inside a function to return user-defined types(class in particular).Suppose we have c++ class called "DMatrix"

```
DMatrix someFunc()
{  
  DMatrix mymat;
  /* Some operations on this matrix */  
  return mymat;  
};
```

Somewhere inside main(), i want to do  :

```
DMatrix d;
d = someFunc();
```

invokes what exactly in terms of stack operations?
I guess in order that the class DMatrix be returnable, it will be sufficient to have a copy constructor(so that instances of this class can be passed via reference) and the = operator defined. Am i right?

MOTIVATION BEHIND: The motivation behind this question is two-fold. 1) I use a library which has defined a matrix type, lets say DMatrix. Can i write functions which do a return of the DMatrix type?
2) The second reason is of course to understand deeper what are the differences at the stack level between return of a custom data type and return of a basic data type like int or double. And therefore, code better classes in C++.May be this has to be made into a separate question.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full response, but yes, you need a copy operator. For your other question, it depends on your ABI. One usual strategy is for the callee to allocate space in its stack frame for the return value, which is then filled out. The result is then copied out by the caller.

Comment: Normally the compiler automatically creates a copy constructor however it is a shallow copy instead of a deep copy.

Comment: Aha, x86 typically makes the caller allocate storage space, then passes a pointer to that space in a register, and thus, the callee must then copy data into the storage at the end. See here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Intel_ABI

Comment: @slugonamission: Yes, you need copy-operations, no, you don't have to necessarily write them on your own.

Comment: @Sdra:yes. i agree.but we do not want shallow copies.that is the objective of this question.to understand what should be ensured.

Comment: @phresnel:wrong about "not necessarily writing them on my own". If the class that we are creating is composed of other classes, we have to ensure that each of those types has a proper copy constructor. If not, we will result in making shallow copies. it might be OK to leave it to the compliler when the class is composed only of basic datatypes. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @jackrobotics: Typically you know if a class is copyable. If not, the doc-writer is to blame. And if all members are copyable, then you don't need to hand-write them, therefore decreasing redundancy, decreasing bug-potential, so increasing quality. If a member is not copyable, you indeed have to hand roll your copy-semantics (or forbid copying altogether). That's why I wrote "not necessarily".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that `DMatrix` needs more than 8 bytes (`sizeof(DMatrix) > 8`), as the compiler might use different techniques for returning small classes.

With the code

```
int main() {
    //...
    DMatrix d;
    d = someFunc();
    //...
}
```

most compilers will "rewrite" that code to something similar to

```
DMatrix d;
DMatrix __retval;
someFunc(__retval);
d = __retval;
```

At the same time, `someFunc` is "rewritten" to something similar to

```
void someFunc(DMatrix& __retval) {
    DMatrix mymat;
    /* Some operations on this matrix */
    // move/copy mymat into __retval
}
```

So, for large classes, most compilers turn return values of that type into a parameter of the function and allocate the storage for the return value in the calling function.

In the above explanation, I have not made use of any of the optimisation possibilities that are present, so it illustrates the "worst-case" behaviour.

---

To be able to return a type from a function, the type needs to have at least a move-constructor (C++11 only) or copy-constructor.
Unless your type explicitly manages some resource (for exaple, memory with new/delete), there is typically no need to write those yourself, because the compiler will generate a suitable one for you.

Comment: So, du coup, if the class has a copy constructor or a move constructor, we can do return instance-of-that-class; without problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a copy constructor but be aware that this is actually one of those interesting scenarios where you'll probably see a semantic difference between the "debug" version of your binary and the "release" version.  Most compilers will optimize away the call to the copy constructor and perform [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) in this instance.  Compilers are specifically allowed to do this with copy constructors by the spec in this circumstance.

Try printing something in your copy constructor, you'll find that it doesn't get printed when you run the release version but it does in the debug version.

Additionally, if you're using C++11, at the point when you return mymat, mymat will be what's known as an rvalue (a temporary object).  It's possible in C++11 to declare a [move constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx) as well as a copy constructor which will explicitly move your object into the outer scope without performing any copying.

Comment: I would also like to add, that in C++11 this optimization can be made explicit. Read about it [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Comment: @DimaRudnik - You're quite right, although in this particular instance, most compilers won't call the move constructor either since elision is performed when RVO is possible even if there is a move constructor.

Comment: @Benj: thanks. So I need both the copy constructot and the = operator is it? I did know about the move constructor brought about in c++11. +1 for it though.

Comment: @jackrobotics - for a return you don't need an assignment operator. In `MyType obj = whatever();` the `=` is an initialization, not an assigmnent.